# OSGi DS: xml file is not generated

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix

I have the following service class:

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
public class Myclass implements MyInterface
{
    @Override
    public String doIt()
    {
        return "This is default bean";
    }
}
```

In pom file I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <_include>
                        -target/classes/META-INF/beans.bnd
                    </_include>
                    <Export-Package></Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package>com.company.temp.*</Private-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    <plugins>
</build>
```

The problem is xml file for DS is not generated. Besides, there is no Service-Component line in manifest file. Where is my mistake (PS java8)?

Comment: @Sean Bright What do you mean? If you could make it to compile, could you just provide all the files?

Comment: @Sean Bright  it says `bundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are planning to use the standard DS annotations (not the felix ones). Then simply use the config below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <_dsannotations>*</_dsannotations>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also have a [DS tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/BIDe) if you need a complete example.

Comment: Thank you. It did the trick. As always... one small line of code. Could you explain what is Blueprint? I can't understand how to translate this word to my native language.

Comment: Blueprint is another dependency injection framework for OSGi. It is derived from the spring syntax and quite similar to it. You can find some examples for it in my other tutorials.

Comment: Could you say - what is the right method to add properties to @Component? when I do `@Component(immediate = false,properties = {"name=stub"})` or `@Component(immediate = false,properties = {"stub"})` I get felix xml entry parser exception.

Comment: I got an example in my tutorial: property="osgi.remote.interfaces:String=*"

Comment: Thank you. I tried @Component(immediate = false,properties = {"name:String=stub"}) but have thre same problem.